# jQuery: how to match final parts of ids

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

In order to open popup with some content, I have many tag anchors whose ids start with "poc" like poc1, poc2, poc3...
At the same way, I have the same number of tag div whose ids start with "pop" like pop1, pop2, pop3... How can I match them in jQuery so that
poc1 --> pop1
poc2 --> pop2
I'm writing something like

```
jQuery("a[id^='poc']").click(function() {
    jQuery('#pop1').bPopup();
});
```

but instead of "pop1" I need the correspondent pop according to the final value of poc. Is it possible?

Comment: use data attr to store the id of pop in that respective poc element. Then, on click read data-attr.

Comment: I suggest that you add a classname for those items.. it will be easier and nicer..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get the specific number by replacing the string `poc` from the clicked element's id:

```
jQuery("a[id^='poc']").click(function() {
    var num = $(this).attr('id').replace('poc','');
    jQuery('#pop' + num).bPopup();
});
```

**Example**

Click on each of the `poc` elements and the respective `pop` element will get red

```js
$('[id^=poc]').on('click', function() {
  var num = $(this).attr('id').replace('poc','');
  $('[id^=pop]').removeAttr('style');
  $('#pop' + num).css({'color':'red'});
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span id="poc1">poc1</span>
<span id="poc2">poc2</span>
<span id="poc3">poc3</span>
<span id="pop1">pop1</span>
<span id="pop2">pop2</span>
<span id="pop3">pop3</span>
```

Comment: anyway, to make it work $ must be replaced by jQuery...still I don't understand why everybody writes $ when jQuery is required... I'm too ignorant :(

Comment: $ is an alias for jQuery. You can use both of them as soon as there is no other js library that may cause a namespace conflict

Answer (score 1):

I'd recommend you to use [`data`](https://api.jquery.com/data/) attribute as follow:

1. Add Common Class to all the anchor elements
2. Add `data-target` element to anchors to store the target `div` id
3. Bind events using `class`
4. Use `data-target` value in `event handler`

**HTML**

```
<a id="poc1" data-target="#pop1" class="pocLinks"> Click Here </a>
<!--         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

**Javascript**

```
jQuery(".pocLinks").on('click', function() {
    $($(this).data('target')).bPopup();
});
```

If you don't want to change your existing HTML.

You can use [`regex`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions) to extract number from the `id` of the clicked element.

```
jQuery("a[id^='poc']").click(function() {
    var no = $(this).attr('id').match(/\d+/)[0];

    $('#pop1' + no).bPopup();
});
```

**Regex**

1. `/`: Regex delimiter
2. `\d`: Matches any number
3. `+`: Matches the previous entity one or more times

Answer (score 1):

1. Parse the current ID - `this.id`
2. Use it as a selector, for `bPopup()`

---

```
jQuery("a[id^='poc']").click(function() {
    var num = this.id.split('poc').pop();
    jQuery('#pop' + num).bPopup();
});
```

**[Reference](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/)**

Answer (score 1):

Save yourself a var based on kapantzak's solution:

```
jQuery("a[id^='poc']").click(function() {
    jQuery( $(this).attr('id').replace('poc','#pop') ).bPopup();
});
```